# Pass data from external form to On Premise?

Tags: 2013, rest, external-users

Are there options to pass data from an external form (ideally) to an On Premise SharePoint.

I'm attempting to collect data from external users who won't be granted access to our SharePoint.

I see how it can be done via SPO, but not on-premise

Comment: Do you want to insert data in SharePoint list using REST API?

Comment: REST is a good possibility to pass form content to an on-prem system

Answer (score 0):

You can Insert Items into SharePoint List by using REST API in SharePoint 2013 using example mentioned in below link.

[Insert Items into List by using REST API in SharePoint 2013](http://sharepointkitchen.blogspot.com/2014/11/insert-into-list-items-by-using-rest.html)

**Notes**

1. You need to change the column names according to your SharePoint Column's internal names.
2. You have to change the list Name & URL.
3. If you want specific items from list than you can query in below line after `?`

   **REST URL**

   ```
   /_api/lists/getbytitle('TestList')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName"
   ```
4. You need to Check Data types of SharePoint list columns & match them into your external form.

I hope this solution will help you to achieve your goal..!

If you need any help than please let me know.

Comment: I'm familiar with consuming rest data, but the key issue is getting from an external form to an on-prem destination.